# Can't set radio button checked value with webbrowser control

Tags: html, vb.net

I'm having trouble setting a radio button via a webbrowser control in VB.NET. This is the HTML code I'm trying to act upon:

```
<td align="right">
Afficher statuts&nbsp;:
 </td>
<td>

<label for="Company">
    <input type="radio" id="Services" value="true" name="requestinfo_0" />
    Company
</label>

<label for="Partener">
    <input type="radio" id="Workload" value="false" name="requestinfo_0" />
    Partener
</label>

<label for="All">
    <input type="radio" id="All" value="" name="requestinfo_0" />
    All
</label>
```

The solution I found from searching shows it should work like this, but it doesn't!

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Workload").SetAttribute("Checked", True)
```

But I believe I would need to specify the name as well as from what I can tell it's possible to have more than 1 ID as "Workload" but in a radio button with a different name. But I can't see where or how to write the code accordingly.

I'm doing this in Visual Studio 2019 in Visual Basic.

Comment: Why you don't use a `<asp:RadioButton ID="yourID" runat="server" />` control? It's more easy access to ID from code behind.

Comment: I have no control over the web page! I am scraping the existing page!

Comment: @AngelCantu OP is trying to manipulate some HTML from another page. What kind of server-side control was used to render it (if any) is irrelevant. When viewing another web page on another site, we can only see the generated HTML, not the server code.

Comment: @Peter It would be invalid HTML if there was more than one element with the same ID, not that that stops it from happening by accident. (1) If you open the page in a browser and then open your browser's developer tools (press F12), go to the "Console", and enter `document.getElementById("Workload")` does it show some HTML or does it say `null`? (2) Have you given the page long enough to render before trying to access the DOM?

Comment: OK I just realized the ID is case sensitive so the first instant is 'All' and the second is 'all' ! So there is no repeated ID's. Yes the page is given ample time to complete before the next step is executed!  Even when I don't execute any other steps, I just let the page wait for manual input! The radio button doesn't change!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using a click event! Works fine now!

```
For Each curElement As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
            If curElement.GetAttribute("type") = "radio" AndAlso curElement.GetAttribute("id") = "Services" Then
                curElement.SetAttribute("checked", "checked")

            End If
            If curElement.GetAttribute("type") = "radio" AndAlso curElement.GetAttribute("id") = "Radio3" Then
                curElement.SetAttribute("checked", "checked")
            End If
            If curElement.GetAttribute("type") = "radio" AndAlso curElement.GetAttribute("id") = "all" Then
                curElement.SetAttribute("checked", "checked")
            End If
        Next
```

Pete

Answer (score 1):

You must to do that **after your WebBrowser have finished to load the document**. A little example below:

```
        WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://html.com/input-type-checkbox/")
        AddHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, Sub(senderObj As Object, eObj As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
                                                      Dim love As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("love")
                                                      If love IsNot Nothing Then
                                                          love.SetAttribute("checked", "checked")
                                                      End If
                                                  End Sub
```

Comment: Thats how I did it! The code to change the radio button is in the sub pointed to by WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted.  I`m starting to wonder if I have to do it by clicking the button!  As in el.InvokeMember("click")

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: unfortunately its a corporate website

Comment: In some cases you cannot have access on DOM elements if those is generated in runtime by javascript the only way to have access is by javascript. One try you can get is that you try to navigate on your url from a webbrowser (firefox or chrome) and take a look if you are able to find your element by developer options

Comment: I did the F12 to open the developer console and can document.getElementById("Workload") and it finds it.

Comment: Bro, you need to select them by pointer cursor on the right side (there isn't mode to do that as you said)

Comment: If I do F12 and on the console and type in document.getElementById("Services") the system returns 
<input id="Services" type="radio" value="true" name="requestinfo_0">  On the right side I see watches and stacks and can`t see any radio buttons let alone one named Services!

Comment: Yes but in this mode you can acces by javascript. I said that before in comments above. You need to explore elements with pointer cursor positioned on the left side of dev window

Comment: The code on the left is numbered from 1 to 768. The code I posted in the first post is from the Body section!  I'm sorry but I don`t know what you mean by find my code by developer options!  I does not seem to be generated by Java, but then again I`m no expert!  So forgive my ignorance and if you could give me more to go on!

Comment: I have a second part to this code that requests a download of an Excel file once the radio boxes are selected! And if fires properly! Its right after the WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Workload").SetAttribute("Checked", True)

Comment: Dim teststr As String
            For Each el As HtmlElement In els
                teststr = el.GetAttribute("href")
                'Debug.Print(el.GetAttribute("href"))
                'If teststr.Contains("/GetFile to export_to_Excel") Then
                    el.InvokeMember("click")

                End If

            Next

Comment: I'm so sorry but I don't realize what you want to do, your explanation is incomplete, partial

Comment: I have a radio button called requestinfo_0 that has 3 choices and I want to activate the second choice! (Workload).